# Will es6 harmony export create instance every time when exporting a const?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I am trying to write a simple WebGL program in es6. Here is one file that is supposed to bring in the `canvas` context whenever it is imported to a file. The idea is to create the `context` once and share it across files.

```
import { getDisplay } from './get-display'; // document.getElementById('my canvas')
import { getWebGLContext } from './get-webgl-context'; // canvas.getContext('webgl')
/** 
 * Gets the WebGL Contexts and exports the reference
*/
export const gl = getWebGLContext(getDisplay());
```

The question is if the sentence `gl = getWebGLContext(getDisplay())` will be executed every time an import is made? Or is it evaluated once and injected in a `DI` fashion? How does Harmony import/export work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `gl = getWebGLContext(getDisplay())` will get executed **once**, when the module is evaluated; every module importing it receives a binding to the same `gl` constant.

In fact, if `gl` were a variable, not a constant, changes your module made to it would be visible to other modules that had imported it; imported bindings are *live*. For example, given this module:

`foo.js`:

```
export let answer = 42;
export const doubleAnswer = () => answer *= 2;
```

and `bar.js` which uses it:

```
import { answer } from './foo.js';

export const showAnswer = () => {
    console.log("showing", answer);
};
```

and a main module that uses both:

```
import { answer, doubleAnswer } from './foo.js';
import { showAnswer } from './bar.js';

console.log("a", answer);
showAnswer();
doubleAnswer();
console.log("b", answer);
showAnswer();
```

The output when you run that main module is:

```
a 42
showing 42
b 84
showing 84
```

Note how both the main module and `bar.js` saw the changes that code in `foo.js` made to `answer`.

More on modules:

- On MDN - [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)
- In Axel Rauschmayer's [Exploring ES6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html)

Comment: So all modules are evaluated in a pre-processing way or evaluated only when the execution encounters a file with the particular import?

Comment: @sabithpocker: Modules are evaluated when they're needed. A module that's never imported anywhere is never executed.

Comment: Its an awesome thing to know that imported bindings are *live*, never had that idea before.

Comment: Awesome example. My blockers are gone, let me go back to coding :) Thank You.